# Jetpack Compose starting animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've found nice artcle about dots animation - https://proandroiddev.com/compose-animations-in-real-time-6068f10595ba, https://github.com/halilozercan/madewithcompose/tree/main/dotsandlines/src/main/java/com/halilibo/dotsandlines. Now I hust want to try run this code on my android-device, but I can't understand how should I start this animation using the modifier. I've tried comething like this in method `onCreate`

```
setContent {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                    .dotsAndLines(Color.Red, 3f, 4f, 1000f, 1f, 40f) // just some params
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {}
}
```

I guess I've missed something important